# AH01382: Request header read timeout -> locate slow-served resources

Tags: apache-2.4

The log files of some low-use apache web servers are polluted by lines like:

```
[reqtimeout:info] [pid 995890:tid 140198394422976] [client 37.103.75.185:49577] AH01382: Request header read timeout
```

VM is Debian, `/etc/apache2/mods-available/reqtimeout.conf` is plain default:

```
 RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,minrate=500
```

As among the IP addresses show up my own IP, I'm certain it's no denial of service.

How can I know which resource is served slow by my web server?

The apache2 web server is actually a reverse proxy, but proxy pass has a shorter timeout:

```
 ProxyPass /smartcard http://localhost:8080/smartcard connectiontimeout=5 timeout=15
```

Comment: mod_reqtimeout measures requests, not responses, so which resource is served slow in your webserver does not adjust to what this module does.